# Iterate over all possible combinations of columns and rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe, iteration, combinatorics

I am looking for some way of iterating over all possible combinations of columns and rows in a numerical dataframe. So it could possibly look like this (just a few of the many possible combinations there could be):

- 1st iteration: Column A + Row 1
- 2nd iteration: Column B + Row 1
- 3rd iteration: Column A + Column B + Row 1
- 4th iteration: Column A + Column B + Row 1 + Row 2
- and so on and on...

For each combination of columns and rows a simple mathematical calculation shall be carried out and its result shall be stored to a dataframe `result`. This way I want to eventually find the combination of columns and rows that yields the highest/lowest calculation result.

So my code looks like this (with respect to the calculation):

```
calc = sum(sum(colSums(data)) + sum(rowSums(data)) / (nrow(data) * ncol(data)))
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I create this **iterating** process in r-code, i.e. the process of trying all possible combinations? I thought of using two nested `for()`-loops, but I am not sure wether this will work (especially how do I address the columns/rows without knowing their names and their number)
2. How can I finally store all the results to a **single** dataframe `result`? `result` should contain the calculation result and the respective combination of columns and rows.

Do you have any ideas how I could solve this?

Here is some data to play around with:

```
data = structure(list(GDP = c(18.2, 8.5, 54.1, 1.4, 2.1, 83.6, 17), 
    Population = c(1.22, 0.06, 0, 0.54, 2.34, 0.74, 1.03), Birth.rate = c(11.56, 
    146.75, 167.23, 7, 7, 7, 10.07), Income = c(54, 94, 37, 95, 
    98, 31, 78), Savings = c(56.73, 56.49, 42.81, 70.98, 88.24, 
    35.16, 46.18)), .Names = c("GDP", "Population", "Birth.rate", 
    "Income", "Savings"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -7L))
```

Comment: Not much clear to me. What do you mean by `combinations of columns and rows`? Could you provide examples?

Comment: i do not see the point from what you described. Since you look for the max and all number are positive (is it always the case?), you sum your entire columns and rows with `sum(data)`. For the min, you just need to select one row and one column and do this for all the possible combinations:
 `min(rowSums(expand.grid(colSums(data), rowSums(data))))`

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel: I am eventually needing it for a kmeans clustering, the "calc"- code I provided is just a dummy. For kmeans clustering it the choice of columns and rows is very important, does it become clearer?

Comment: @nicola: I edited my question, does it become clearer?

Comment: Is for instance `Col A + Col B + Row 2` (without `Row 1`) allowed?

Comment: yes, **every** possible combination of rows AND columns, is it clearer now?

Comment: Do you know how to count the number of combos you are seeking given `nrow(data)` and `ncol(data)`?

Comment: I will repeat my question again ... are all your number positive on your real data?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: no, they could also be negative

Comment: I'm not sure you are aware of the complexity of what you are trying to do. Anyway, I'll answer my own question. The number of your combos are `(2^ncol(data)-1)*(2^nrow(data)-1)`. If `data` has something like 30 rows, that number become huge. Anyway, to get started try `unlist(lapply(seq_along(data),function(x) combn(data,x,simplify=FALSE)),recursive=FALSE)`. It will give you all combos of just columns. For each of the element of the list, you have to choose the rows.

Comment: Your math is off and I asked the above to check whether you are aware of the number of combos. See my previous comment.

Comment: @nicola yes you are right! thank you for pointing me towards it!

Comment: @nicola: The iteration over rows is actually not that important, it is more the iteration over columns, in this case the complexity reduces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully following what we are trying to achieve, maybe this is a start:

```
library(data.table)

cc <- 1:ncol(data)
rr <- 1:nrow(data)

rbindlist(
  lapply(cc, function(i){
    ccN <- combn(cc, i)
    rbindlist(
      apply(ccN, 2, function(iN){
        rbindlist(
          lapply(rr, function(j){
            rrN <- combn(rr, j)
            rbindlist(
              apply(rrN, 2, function(jN){
                data.frame(
                  Sum = sum(c(
                    unlist(data[jN, ]),
                    unlist(data[, iN]))),
                  Desc = paste(c("rows",jN,"cols",iN), collapse = ",")
                )
              })
            )
          })
        )
      })
    )
  })
)


#          Sum                              Desc
#   1:  326.61                     rows,1,cols,1
#   2:  490.70                     rows,2,cols,1
#   3:  486.04                     rows,3,cols,1
#   4:  359.82                     rows,4,cols,1
#   5:  382.58                     rows,5,cols,1
#  ---                                          
#3933: 2687.14   rows,1,2,3,5,6,7,cols,1,2,3,4,5
#3934: 2560.92   rows,1,2,4,5,6,7,cols,1,2,3,4,5
#3935: 2556.26   rows,1,3,4,5,6,7,cols,1,2,3,4,5
#3936: 2720.35   rows,2,3,4,5,6,7,cols,1,2,3,4,5
#3937: 2862.06 rows,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,cols,1,2,3,4,5
```